# SonarQube - Community edition - Reporting Plugin

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, reporting

I have SonarQube 7.0 -Community version.

I was looking for some reporting plugin that would bring the code smells, bugs and other issues in a PDF report.

I found Governance report plugin, but that was only for commercial editions.

Is there any reporting plugin in the community edition that would fit my need?

Comment: Maybe you could build a report based on the Web-API.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this open source app: https://github.com/cnescatlab/sonar-cnes-report

It is officially available on SonarQube Marketplace.

It generates a docx report and an xlsx file with all issues. You can also generate markdown and csv files based on your own templates.

Comment: This plugin isn't working for latest version, i.e community edition - version 9.6. Check this matrix https://github.com/cnescatlab/sonar-cnes-report#compatibility-matrix

Comment: Together with the compat matrix mentioned by @AbhishekPandey you should also check this issue report with comments about compatibility down to version 9.4 (as I write this): https://github.com/cnescatlab/sonar-cnes-report/issues/270

Comment: this is getting installed in version 8.9.9